# Problem with str_ireplace for a <br /> tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, str-replace, nl2br

I am currently storing a textarea input (HTML) in MySQL database.

The new lines in the textarea are preserved using `nl2br()` function in php.

To post the stored value, I've used the following code:

```
$post = getSinglePost($topic, $postId)[0];  //This is a function that retrieves a single post from my SQL database

$precontent = $post['postContent']; 

$anotherContent = str_ireplace("<br />", "<br>", $precontent);
```

The last line is the one that I am having problem with. For some reason `str_ireplace` works on any other string value than `<br />`.

Could someone point what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Why do you want to change `<br />` to `<br>` anyway?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for editing the post btw.
When I try posting the content it shows as followed:

"Why is this not working?<br /> <br />" . Not sure why it's not converting into new line??? Btw this is the code I used to post: <?= $anotherContent; ?>. Sorry for formatting, I am new to stackoverflow :(

Comment: Not 100% sure, but perhaps you need to convert the `<br />` tag back to a new line - try `str_ireplace("<br />", PHP_EOL, $precontent)`

Comment: Thank you, but the code is still not working. I am wondering if I got the initial problem wrong. Should the "<br />" tag worked in the first place? If so, why would it appear as text instead of functioning as a tag?

Comment: Solved! Thank you. Sorry, but it's because I used "htmlspecialchars" function before storing it to SQL :)

Comment: Good that you sorted it, sometimes it's the things you least expect.

Comment: Absolutely! Your comment directed me to the bug so thank you!